# Flatten Table Pivot style for a Datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I want to view my attendance table using a `datagridview` (vb.net)

This is my sample table

```
Name   |    Date     |  Status  
-------+-------------+--------
John   | 08/08/2015  |   P
Mark   | 08/08/2015  |   A
James  | 08/08/2015  |   L
John   | 08/09/2015  |   A
Mark   | 08/09/2015  |   A
James  | 08/09/2015  |   A
```

And this is what I want my `datagridview` to look like:

```
NAME  | 08/08/2015 | 08/09/2015
------+------------+------------
John  |     P      |     A
Mark  |     A      |     A
James |     L      |     A
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you have tried to make this work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing, in some cases you can create a query or prepared statement to do this for you. These are usually to summarize a fixed set of known columns.  In this case we do not know how many date columns there will be or what they are.  So, we can do it in code.

I used Access instead of mySQL, but the concept is the same.  I also made it more complex by logging attendance by class which do not meet everyday.  The starting data:

[image]

I wont be using the class name in the results, it makes the display too wide.

```vb
Dim sql = <sql>  
           ((Use your own SQL obviously))
           </sql>.Value

Dim dtTemp As New DataTable

' get the data
Using dbcon As OleDbConnection = GetACEConnection(),
    cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, dbcon)

    dbcon.Open()
    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dtTemp)
    End Using

End Using

' unique list of "date" columns in the result set
' ORDERBY Date is in the SQL
Dim colNames = dtTemp.AsEnumerable().
                Select(Function(s) DateTime.Parse(s.Item("Date").ToString).
                        ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")).
                Distinct.ToList()

' unique list of students
Dim Students = dtTemp.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(q) q.Item("Name")).
                Distinct.ToList()

' the final table to use with the DGV
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim colName As String

' add the name and class code designation columns
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(dtTemp.Columns(0).ColumnName, GetType(String)))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(dtTemp.Columns(1).ColumnName, GetType(String)))

' add a "MM/dd/yyyy" text column for each possible class day
For n As Int32 = 0 To colNames.ToArray.Count - 1
    colName = DateTime.Parse(colNames(n).ToString).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(colName, GetType(String)))
Next

Dim newRow As DataRow

' loop thru all students
For Each s In Students
    ' the student-class dataset
    Dim drs As DataRow() = dtTemp.Select(String.Format("Name = '{0}'", s.ToString)).
                            OrderBy(Function(o) o.Item("ClassCode")).ToArray

    ' create list of classes for this student
    Dim classes = drs.AsEnumerable.
            Select(Function(q) q.Item(1).ToString).Distinct.ToArray

    For Each classcode As String In classes
        ' filter the drs results to the current class
        Dim datestat As DataRow() = drs.AsEnumerable.
                Where(Function(q) q.Item(1).ToString = classcode).ToArray

        ' create new row, copy the data from drs.Rows to dt.columns
        newRow = dt.NewRow
        newRow.Item(0) = s
        newRow.Item(1) = classcode
        ' NOTE since not all students will have a class everyday, some
        ' "status" cells will be dbNull!
        For Each statRow In datestat
            Dim cname As String = DateTime.Parse(statRow.Item("Date").
                                                     ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
            newRow.Item(cname) = statRow.Item("Status")
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
    Next

Next

dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = True
dgv.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader)
dgv.DataSource = dt
```

It isnt quite as complex as it may look.

1. Get the master dataset to work on
2. Get a list of unique student names
3. The column names to use comes from a linq query to extract the unique class dates in the data table
4. Create a new `DataTable` for the results.

   - After the `StudentName` and `ClassCode` a loop adds one column for each date that **any** class meets.  The column names/headert text comes from the `ColNames` list/array just created.

With the destination DataTable created, you can start copying data to it.  Again, instead of `OleDB...` objects you would use `MySQL...` object, but they work the same.

1. Loop thru all students in the student list
2. For each, extract a list of all classes they attended from the master data set
3. Loop thru those classes
4. Extract the rows for the current class from the Student-Class dataset
5. Create a new `DataRow` using the Student and Class iteration vars for the first 2 columns.
6. Convert each DateTime value in the current Student-Class dataset to the same format used to create the result columns (`cname`).

   - use it to copy their status: `newRow.Item(cname) = statRow.Item("Status")` to the new row
   - Since the classes dont meet everyday, some cells will be blank (`DbNull`)
7. Add the new row to the final datatable

It would be simpler without the By Class reporting, and just report the status for the entire day.  The Result:

[image]

The most confusing part is using the Date *data* in one datatable as a column *name* in another and stripping out the time portion.

That is just a first pass, so it can likely be refined.  Some of the processing might be able to be done in SQL; the `DateTime.Parse` method to convert the `DateTime` data to a string in the same format (remove the Time etc) could be its own procedure.  I would also use a 2 character year format to make the headers a little narrower.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I love you I love you I love you! I've been stuck in this part for weeks now! Thank you so much! you've been a great help!!!! I love you. Thank you!