# VB.NET MySQL dynamically add values to datatable

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

My query is..

```
Dim qry as String = "SELECT FeeName, Amount FROM FeeTable WHERE DateTaken BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-06' ORDER BY FeeId ASC"
```

Adding columns to Datatable...

```
OpenConnection()
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim dt As New DataTable
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = qry
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While dr.Read
    dt.Columns.Add(dr("FeeName"), GetType(Integer))
End While
dr.Close()
CloseConnection()
```

How can I add values to it so that the `DataTable` looks like below...

```
------------------------------------------
|   Fee 1  |  Fee 2  |  Fee 3  |  Total  |
------------------------------------------
|   100.00 |  350.00 |  200.00 |  650.00 |
------------------------------------------
```

My `query` output is like

```
----------------------------------
|     FeeName      |     Amount  |
----------------------------------
|    Fee 1         |      100.00 |
|    Fee 2         |      350.00 |
|    Fee 3         |      200.00 |
----------------------------------
```

**NOTE:** the `Feename` are dynamic. In the above structure I showed only three `FeeName`s. It could result 10 or 20 more `FeeNames` if the query output shows.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44409204/1070452)??  (it also seems doubtful the FeeName would be integer)

Comment: Nothing. But struggling more than 10 hours I did not find any solution. If you want to differ this from previous, I should say, I asked the previous question for `MySQL` only.

Comment: Have you tried researching `pivot`?

Comment: @Plutonix I tried. But as the fields are dynamic, I failed adding value to it. As the values are integer, I coded as `GetType(Integer)`. And most important thing is, somebody said, "Using MYSQL to do it would be a bad idea and bad practice"

Comment: Thats not what they said - they were talking about the total

Comment: @Plutonix How could I do that ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146116/discussion-between-raj-and-plutonix).

Comment: You could run a query to get the names and use that to craft a proper pivot query filling in the blanks.  Or loop thru a regular datatable of results and [transpose column and row data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32485034/1070452)

Comment: You shouldn't handle output formatting in SQL that's not its main purpose just get your data and write a function to format it: Create a class with Fee Name and amount and for every row add it to the a List(Of YourClass) then just print every item.